# Unable to see entire content of page even when scrolling

Tags: css

Trying to get last card on this page to show when scrolling down. Currently the footer is blocking the bottom of the last card in the article element with class main. I added the following css for the main class but still when scrolling down I cannot see the bottom part of the last card. How do I fix this. Thank you. The entire project can be seen [here](http://z1labs.com/projects/blog/).

```
.main {
    grid-area: main;
    padding: 5px;
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `margin-bottom`

```
.main {
    grid-area: main;
    padding: 5px;
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 75px;
}
```